# Target Unreachable, identifier 'flowScope' resolved to null

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, faces-flow

I'm exploring the Faces Flow feature in JSF 2.2 and I'm getting the following error `Target Unreachable, identifier 'flowScope' resolved to null` when I run the tutorial in this page: http://www.mastertheboss.com/javaee/jsf/faces-flow-tutorial

The sample seems to be really simple, it only have one flow with 3 facelets, with this structure:

[image]

The flow is called `signup`, so I have a folder called `signup` in inside my `WebContent` folder, and 3 facelets, one of them with the same name as the flow as starting node, and a configuration file called `signup-flow.xml`.

This is the content of the starting node (`signiup.xhtml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<h:head>
<title>Signup account</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
    content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form1" styleClass="form">
        <h1>Signup Account</h1>
        <p>Name <h:inputText id="name" value="#{flowScope.name}" /></p>
        <p>Surname: <h:inputText id="surname" value="#{flowScope.surname}" /></p>
        <p>Email: <h:inputText id="email" value="#{flowScope.email}" /></p>     

        <p><h:commandButton id="page2" value="next" action="signup2" /></p>

    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

This is my `SignupBean`:

```
package com.jsf.flow;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped;

@Named
@FlowScoped(value="signup")
public class SignupBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8112971305468080981L;
    private boolean licenseAccepted;

    public SignupBean() { 
    }

    public String getHomeAction() {
        return "/index";
    }
    public boolean isLicenseAccepted() {
        return licenseAccepted;
    }

    public void setLicenseAccepted(boolean licenseAccepted) {
        this.licenseAccepted = licenseAccepted;
    }

    public String accept() {
        if (this.licenseAccepted) {
            return "signup3";
        } else {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "You have to read and accept the license!", "You have to read and accept the license!"));
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my `signup-flow.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">

    <flow-definition id="signup">
        <flow-return id="homePage">
            <from-outcome>#{signupBean.homeAction}</from-outcome>
        </flow-return>
    </flow-definition>
</faces-config>
```

I get the error when I click on the `commandButton` in the `signup.xhtml`, the code seems to be exactly the same as the one in the tutorial, I checked several posts with the same error but nothing seems to work for me.

This is the important part in the stack trace:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /signup/signup.xhtml @12,68 value="#{flowScope.name}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'flowScope' resolved to null
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:95)
```

Worth to mention that I'm using GlassFish 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, I was trying to start the flow calling the initial node using a link, like this:

```
<h:link id="link1" styleClass="link" value="Link" outcome="/signup/signup.xhtml"></h:link>
```

Instead I replaced the link with a `commandButton` and in the `action` parameter I used the flow name, like this:

```
<h:commandButton id="start" value="Signup User" action="signup"/>
```

And now it's working.